# Exit code 3221225477 in vsCode for Julia. How can I solve?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I'm using vsCode with Julia expansion on Windows 10. My Julia code using multi threads. In vsCode for Julia, what does it mean exit code 3221225477. Should I change my julia code? Or is it enough to change the setting of vsCode?

[image]

Comment: There's hardly any way to tell without any code and more error output. The messages being Korean (?) doesn't help, either.

Comment: My code is so long. So i need an abstract for post. It takes time. Understand me. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: This looks more like a vscode problem than a problem with your code, but yes hard to tell exactly what is happening without more context

Comment: Yes, I think it's like a vscode problem.